# Excel column headers turned into headings

Tags: headers, microsoft-excel-365

Excel 365
I have a Table and apparently I did something that turned its column headers into headings. But I cannot figure out what and how to make it happen again.

Any references?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a button within the Design tab (for tables) for this function.  Microsoft has a support article that explains this functionality that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel has a "Freeze Cells" feature that allows you to keep rows/columns always in view when scrolling large documents. Based on your description, I believe this is what you are describing.

To Unfreeze Cells:

1. Go to the **View** menu
2. Select the **Freeze Panes** dropdown
3. Select **Unfreeze**

Hope that helps[image]